# Unable to bulk download PDF's from Explorer view

Tags: 2010, pdf, explorer-view

A user of mine is unable to download files from explorer view in Sharepoint 2010 but it only seems to be PDF's.

Whenever they try to do it they get the following message.

You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this file.

Users are Sharepoint admins and local admins on their machine, I've also tested with my domain admin account and get the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you copy (download) files of a different type to the same target directory with Windows Explorer? Any further details available in the Windows application eventlog or SharePoint ULS?

Comment: Every other file type is fine just PDF's and nothing in the event log or ULS that matches up.

Answer (score 1):

Follow all of the WebDAV troubleshooting tips under "Important points to be remembered when troubleshooting explorer view issues" in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx).

If none of those WebDAV tips help, consider testing with a different browser (different version of IE).

Also, turn on Fiddler and watch what happens when you try to copy PDFs with explorer view.

Hope you find a resolution soon!

Comment: Most of those have already been checked - I'm stumped with this one and can't see any particular traffic with Fiddler on the issue.